# Can we use django rest framework with mongo

Tags: django-rest-framework

Can we use django rest framework with mongodb.

I am trying to setup ths by installing

```
Django==2.0.4

django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.3.1

djangorestframework==3.8.2
mongoengine==0.15.0

pymongo==3.6.1

pytz==2018.4
```

I am also trying to put rest_frame_mongoengine in Django setting.py and ending up with an import error saying that module is not defined.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine

Comment: Here's a useful blogpost: https://medium.com/@vasjaforutube/django-mongodb-django-rest-framework-mongoengine-ee4eb5857b9a

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked DRF-Mongoengine?

https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine

Here's a nice step-by-step tutorial:

https://medium.com/@vasjaforutube/django-mongodb-django-rest-framework-mongoengine-ee4eb5857b9a

Your installed apps should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( ... 'rest_framework' 'rest_framework_mongoengine', ... )
```

Comment: Hi, I have gone through these things already. I have included rest_framework_mongoengine in INSTALLED APPS FILE IN DJANGO SETTINGS. IT IS THROWING THE ABOVE ERROR.

Comment: Is your installed apps set properly? `rest_framework_mongoengine`

Comment: here Is the snippet   INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djmonapp',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_mogoengine',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth'
]

Comment: Error is "  File "/apps/dbtstg/admin/shared/scripts/ratnaveni/djmon/env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework_mogoengine'""

Comment: Did you run `pip install django-rest-framework-mongoengine`
Are you running your server in the right environment where the package is installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed using pip only   pip freeze
Django==2.0.4
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.3.1
djangorestframework==3.8.2
mongoengine==0.15.0
pymongo==3.6.1
pytz==2018.4

Comment: A word of caution for others - it looks like DRF-Mongoengine is no longer active as per this thread: https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/259